# For rails, is creating the 'ar_internal_metadata' table with a handwritten migration a good idea?

Tags: ruby, database-migration, ruby-on-rails-5.1

When I run a migration, the 'ar_internal_metadata' table keeps being stripped out of the schema.

```
  create_table 'ar_internal_metadata', primary_key: 'key', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime 'created_at', null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at', null: false
    t.string 'value'
  end
```

If I were to create the 'ar_internal_metadata' with a manual migration, would it work fine or cause problems?

Comment: "is a good idea?" - probably not. Depends on what you're after. Are you intentionally going to mess with AR internals?

Comment: Nope, just stop rails from stripping it out when running migrations, I'm getting annoyed at having to manually add it back in each time.

Comment: Judging from the docs, rails should add it itself, automatically and behind the scenes. Was it not your experience?

Comment: no, becuase rails strips the table out when I run a migration, hence me asking if manually adding it would cause problems

Comment: Define "strips the table out". Does it not appear in schema.rb afterwards? But is it in the actual database, either your version or rails'?

Comment: At least you get to use rails 5 and figure all this stuff out. Because of this I should have an easier life later :)

Comment: strips out of the schema

Comment: But it is there in the database?

Comment: no it does not.

Comment: Then I think we can safely conclude that this is __not__ a good idea. :)

Comment: "no it does not" - I'd need to verify that myself. Looks improbable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> keeps being stripped out of the schema.

This is [expected behaviour](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2840c429cc1cf0edb6e6549f7581b782021a71f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb#L239-L243):

```
  # activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb
  def ignored?(table_name)
    [ActiveRecord::Base.schema_migrations_table_name, ActiveRecord::Base.internal_metadata_table_name, ignore_tables].flatten.any? do |ignored|
      ignored === remove_prefix_and_suffix(table_name)
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is a system table. You should not need to create it yourself.

Comment: But why is it expected behaviour? are they not using it anymore or somthing?

Comment: @Thermatix: because it's a system/service table and has nothing to do with your app. Hence, no reason to be in your schema.rb

Comment: So why was it there in first place? I'm only adding it back in becuase I've been told that it needs to be in the schema, if it's not supposed to be there then why was it in the schema?

Comment: @Thermatix Do you use something called scenic, by any chance? there was a bug in it which caused this table to be dumped to schema.rb.

Comment: We do not, still this does answer my question, I'll mark it as such thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: It is possible you were switching back and forth between Rails 5 and 4.x branches. If so, and you ran a migration while in Rails 4 after upgrading to Rails 5 then that table will be added to the schema because Rails 4 doesn't know to exclude it, and the Rails 5 upgrade added to your DB.